# Why is Keras' predict-function throwing "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I have a Sequential model that is trained and compiles successfully, but when running prediction raises the error as stated in the title.

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore')

# Numpy arrays
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = Prepr_data.process()

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(84,)), Activation('relu'),
    Dense(11), Activation('softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=91)

pred = model.predict(X_test, Y_test)

print(pred)
```

X-arrays contain independent variables, while Y-arrays contain the dependent variable. That is, Y-arrays contain the labels I am trying to predict, and X contain the rest of the data. All four arrays are numpy arrays of equal length. All data present are one-hot encoded (totalling 84 columns in X, 11 in Y). All data are of dtype float64.

I am quite new to ML so there might just be a very trivial issue I am overlooking ... any help appreciated!

Comment: We don't use the true labels in predict - it should be `model.predict(X_test)`; please check the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict).

Comment: I knew it was something trivial.. thank you.